# Converting a String to ByteBuffer

Tags: java, arrays

I want to put a string into a `MappedByteBuffer` so I converted the string into a byte array first and put it into the buffer, but when I invoke the `.hasArray()` method it returns false, where is the problem ?

Here is my code:

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("F:\\Studying\\operating system\\OSTask1\\file.txt");
        FileChannel ch = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.READ);
        MappedByteBuffer buf = ch.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 4096);
        String s = "hello world";
        byte[] arr = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        buf.wrap(arr);
        System.out.println(buf.hasArray());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: [`wrap(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap-byte:A-) is a `static` method of `ByteBuffer`, which **returns** a new `ByteBuffer` object wrapping the specified array. Which means, you are using it incorrectly in your code.

Comment: Since you create buf as a MappedByteBuffer from a file, do you somehow expect the wrap method to write the string to that file?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`buf.wrap(arr)` returns the new ByteBuffer. So change your code to:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = buf.wrap(arr);
System.out.println(byteBuffer.hasArray());
```

Comment: Note that the wrap method is static. It does not make sense at all to create a MappedByteBuffer from a file, as done here, to use that reference to invoke the wrap method. If you want a new ByteBuffer wrapping the array, you should implement `ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr);` I have the impression though, that OP wants to write the string to the open file.

Comment: @jarnbjo Yes, you are totally right about usage of wrap method but question was about the hasArray() result. I just wanted to show the missed point quickly. Thanks for details.